# What is best practice for adding number of views to an object using GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I presently have an AWS Amplify project using a graphQL schema and want to track the number of times an object is viewed.  Suppose in the following schema a user creates a blog.  Now I want to track the number of time other users view this blog.  Although users can obviously view it as many times as they like I want to only count a maximum of one view per user.

```
type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  views: Int
  Author: User @connection
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

At the moment I'm thinking to create an additional table with just the BlogId and UserId and do this in two steps.  Firstly to check that table for whether or not the user has viewed the blog and if not incrementing the blog views.  But wondering if there is a better way to achieve this?

```
type BlogViews @model {
  id: ID!
  BlogId: ID!
  UserId: ID!
}
```

Comment: I would also like to know the outcome of this, I am thinking of using a lambda at the moment but am unsure of if there's a better way

Comment: What I’m thinking is to make the id of the BlogViews a combination of userid and blogid and adding a lambda as a dynamodb trigger when the new BlogView is created.   This way the id will be unique and only one can be created once for each combination of user and blog.  Lambda will increment the view.  Seems to work well.

Comment: Im looking into lambda triggers right now and I think it's the way to go: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/function#usage https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function https://amplify-sns.workshop.aws/en/50_follow_timeline/30_function_directive.html

Comment: I’ve used them before and work very well. amplify add function and just make sure you choose lambda trigger and dynamodb stream

Comment: ok I did that, but I'm kinda curious how I initiate a revision to the model that was just the trigger, the tutorial says to use axios but i have doubts that it will function because I cannot get the actual value of the key I'm trying to increment: https://gist.github.com/JakeTrock/613a80db4875ef0fee84a6904e019e27

Comment: when you add the trigger, you can access. the new item you just created in the lambda from "event.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.blogId.S.toString()". And then just do an update on the blog incrementing the views.  in fact views is a reserved name so you would. have to name. it something else and I'm sure we are both not using blogs but that's the approach.  also you need to manually add a permission for your lambda to invoke update on the blog table.